# Live Plotting using pyqtgraph

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqtgraph

I wish to read data from a spectrometer and plot a frequency vs intensity graph inside a PyQt5 Gui, I have done all other stuff and the following code plots a graph:

```
plot1 = pg.PlotWidget()
plot2 =pg.PlotWidget()
layout.addWidget(plot1,2,3,15,10)
layout.addWidget(plot2,100,3,5,10)


sptdll.getFrame(byref(spectra),0xFFFF)  #this is just that my program takes data from a dll file
b = np.frombuffer(spectra, dtype=np.uint16)

plot1.plot(data,b[0:3653],pen='g')      # data is my x axis array, and b is y axis
```

Now my problem I want this graph to run live, that is change with time, I was able to do that in matplotlib as follows:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    sptdll.getFrame(byref(spectra),0xFFFF)
    b = np.frombuffer(spectra, dtype=np.uint16)
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(data,b[0:3653])


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=10)

plt.show()
```

but since i want to do the same with pyqtgraph inside my GUI; can somebody help, I am attaching the current screenshot of my GUI.

Image of Gui, I need the green graph to go live.

[image]